# Grails stuck on Running Grails application

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

when I run `grails run-app`

It gets to `Running Grails application` and sits there.

How do I debug this? Are there more logs I can turn on? What is it doing? Are there methods or configs that grails looks at when "Running" the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Config.groovy`, there's a hash for logging.  By default, mine looks like:

```
log4j = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
    //
    appenders {
        console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    }

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}
```

Just change 'error' to 'all'.

Alternately, you might want to turn on 'info' logging for all loggers by default:

```
log4j = {
    root {
        info()
    }
    …
}
```